# Remove link from header of widget

Tags: php, wordpress

in my wordpress theme I want to customize title of widget with different color and remove link from title of widget.

```
                    <div id="widget2">

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <?php if (!dynamic_sidebar('widget2')) : ?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
```

Unfortunately the title of widget get link of first row of list-item.
how can I solve it?

Comment: I want to remove link just from title

Comment: please check footer of http://kheime133.ir/

Comment: you need to modify code of sidebar widget2, can you modify your question and show the code of the widget?

Comment: the code has been edited. I want to just remove link from title of widget

Comment: as i can see on your site, you've already resolved the problem

Comment: found it!
in wordpress the short-code for widget add link to <li> automatically and <a></a> is extra.